# Angular4 Material Input not displaying properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to put Material in an angular4 project where i copy/pasted the exampel with a table. The programmatic part is working as expected when i type a customer name (it filters as it should) and the table below shows perfectly good. The problem is that the matInput inside the mat-form-field is not displayed correctly. When you type something the typed text overlays the placeholder, instead of the placeholder going floating up. Here is my code and screenshot of the problem.

Console shows no errors or anything, everything seems to be working fine, it's a css issue with the input field what i'm facing.

[image]

Here is my component code .html

```
        <app-topmenu></app-topmenu>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
              <div class="example-header">
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Customer Name">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my component .ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MainconfService } from '../services/mainconf.service';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
     dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

     applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
       filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
       filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
       this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
     }

  constructor(public mainconf: MainconfService ) {

   }




  ngOnInit() {
       this.mainconf.authenticate();
  }






}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoffComponent } from './logoff/logoff.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
// import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { MainconfService } from './services/mainconf.service';
import { TopmenuComponent } from './topmenu/topmenu.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatCardModule, MatTableModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule  } from '@angular/material';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'logoff', component: LogoffComponent },
  { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LogoffComponent,
    TopmenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: false } // <-- debugging purposes only
  ),

  // NgbModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatCardModule, MatTableModule, MatFormFieldModule , MatInputModule

  ],
  providers: [ApiService, MainconfService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is the material module included in your module imports, `MatInputModule` I think?

Comment: yes  - else I think it'd produce an error anyway. but it is in imports yes

Comment: I think problem is @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; doesnt load the css. Where is this supposed to be ? i have it in my .css file

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the problem, I'll state in case someone is in similar situation.

I need to place

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

inside styles.css (which I havent before).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple and stupid, because it works fine in a previous branch of my code.  I just couldn't figure out what exactly I changed that broke it.

Comment: the purple-green.css dont work well for me I change to indigo pink, and started working fine... not sure if that specific theme is broke.

Comment: Then why putting on `angular.json` it was not working . I had put inside an array of styles `./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css` , whats wrong with that . Was angular not importing from there , why put in `styles.css`

Comment: I see problem still exists.

Comment: So basically my favorite theme is just borked? That's frustrating. Has this issue been reported to the team on github?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with purple-green.css theme selected.
Change the theme to indigo ping it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and wracking my brain but then I noticed an unrelated error (null reference in a different HTML block in my template) that was somehow causing the input to not render correctly. If this is still happening to you in 2023 then maybe it's user error :-D