# Why the mat-form-field is not showing up?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-form-field

On my package.json I have `@angular/material": "^13.3.8"` but I'm using the 13.3.7 version and `Angular CLI: 13.3.7`. I'm just copying the codes from the Angular Material and already imported the `MatInputModule` on my `app.module.ts`. My problem is the mat-form-field is not showing on my browser. I need to click the area where my input is then it will show up. As you can see in the image below:

Before I clicked the mat-form-field

[image]

After I clicked the mat-form-field

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Here's my code:

product.component.html

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Search...">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
NgbModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatTableModule,
MatCardModule,
MatPaginatorModule,
MatInputModule,
MatIconModule,
MatButtonModule,
FormsModule,
FontAwesomeModule,
MatFormFieldModule,
ReactiveFormsModule
```

Comment: I solved this problem on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380167/angular4-material-input-not-displaying-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to import the material style in style.scss or maybe in angular.json style array.
Here is an example

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: Any idea why this answer was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

import BrowserAnimationsModule in your AppModule

import it by

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

add BrowserAnimationsModule  to imports array

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code to your src/style.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.